# Dart convert List<int> to a uint32 number, List size is 4

Tags: dart

I want to convert a List to Uint32 number, how could I do?

List a = [0x00,0x02,0x13,0x04];

// 135940 how can I get this number in dart
// or just shift data myself to get the uint32 number?

Answer (score 0):

OK!

I've solved this!

use `ByteData.view(Uint8List.fromList(a).buffer).getUint32(0)`

Comment: A variant version is `Uint8List.fromList(a).buffer.asByteData().getUint32(0)`. You can also just combine them manually, as you say: `(a[0] << 24) + (a[1] << 16) + (a[2] << 8) + a[3]`. That's probably more efficient, if efficiency is important, since it doesn't require allocating a new list. The important thing to recognize here is that you want a *big endian* interpretation (also known as Network Byte Order). That is why `ByteData` is useful, and `Uint32List` is not, because the latter uses platform byte order, which is little endian on many current CPUs.